# Hide Loading Screen In ArFragment

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I am new to ArCore and using ArFragment. I want to show my "menu" view when the planes are detected and hide this loading image.
[image]

I used "**arFragment.getArSceneView.getScene().setOnUpdateListener**".
Whenever I implement my own "setOnUpdateListener",I am able to show my menu but this loading image does not hide. This image only hides automatically when I do not implement the updateListener.
Here is the fragment from activity_main.xml and listener from MainActivity.java

```
<fragment android:name="com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment"
    android:id="@+id/ux_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

        ArSceneView arSceneView =arFragment.getArSceneView();
    arSceneView.getScene().setOnUpdateListener(
            frameTime -> {
                Frame frame = arSceneView.getArFrame();
                if (frame == null) {
                    return;
                }
                if (frame.getCamera().getTrackingState() != TrackingState.TRACKING) {
                    return;
                }

                for (Plane plane : frame.getUpdatedTrackables(Plane.class)) {
                    if (plane.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING) {
                        Log.e("********************","");
                        hsv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: I'll pass along  the feedback, it would be nice to have a way of enabling and disabling the animation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can work around having the plane discovery view always show on startup by hiding the view, then setting it to null so it won't reappear.  In `onCreate()` add:

```
arFragment = (ArFragment) 
        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ux_fragment);
arFragment.getPlaneDiscoveryController().hide();
arFragment.getPlaneDiscoveryController().setInstructionView(null);
```

Comment: According to documentation, "If setOnUpdateListener(Scene.OnUpdateListener) is set, then onUpdate(FrameTime) must be called manually". Is this "frameTime" arrow function also called onUpdate function ? arSceneView.getScene().setOnUpdateListener(
                frameTime -> {});

Comment: Yes, this is Java 8 syntax.  The frameTime is the variable passed to the listener method and the -> points to the code to run.  This can be a function or a single statement, or a group of statements in braces.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The following is no longer necessary in recent Sceneform versions. If you can use `addOnUpdateListener` instead of `setOnUpdateListener` you don't have to do what I describe below.

If you set your own `OnUpdateListener` you have to call `arFragment.onUpdate(frameTime);` in your implementation of the `OnUpdateListener`. In your case that would be:

```
ArSceneView arSceneView = arFragment.getArSceneView();
arSceneView.getScene().setOnUpdateListener(
        frameTime -> {
            Frame frame = arSceneView.getArFrame();
            if (frame == null) {
                return;
            }
            if (frame.getCamera().getTrackingState() != TrackingState.TRACKING) {
                return;
            }

            for (Plane plane : frame.getUpdatedTrackables(Plane.class)) {
                if (plane.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING) {
                    Log.e("********************","");
                    hsv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
            arFragment.onUpdate(frameTime);
        });
```

This way you can still show the InstructionView without it staying once planes have been discovered.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following code which is maybe easier to use. By extending the ArFragment class, you have multiple possibilities to manipulate the view and behavior.

OnResume calls onStart() which will show the planeDiscoveryController (the hand moving around) until it finds a Plane. This is why I call hide() in my own onResume method.

OnWindowFocusChanged from BaseArFragment will force the screen to expand into Full Screen. By overriding the method, I remove the flags which are changing my screen and just keep the flag for maintaining the screen open and bright.

```
class ProductArFragment : ArFragment() {

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        planeDiscoveryController.hide()
    }

    override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
        activity?.let { act ->
            if (hasFocus) {
                act.window.addFlags(WindowManager
                        .LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
            }
        }
    }
}
```